# Time taken for a body to crash into the sun

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, gravity, integration

> A small body starts from rest towards the Sun from the position of Earth, find the total time it takes for the body to crash into the Sun (assume Sun is a point object and no other forces act on the system).

My approach to this question:

1. $a =  \frac{GM}{r^2}$ for the body at any r distance form Sun.
2. Next I found out velocity, $v = \sqrt{2GM(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{R})} $, where R is initial distance
3. From here we get $\int_{R}^{0} \frac{dx}{v}$

Now how do I integrate this monstrosity? Is there any easier and faster way than the one above?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But the earth is anyways in a free fall towards the sun, it just has enough tangential speed to miss it and keep an almost circular orbit... So you would need to decelerate your test mass?

Comment: I think, you are missing a square in your (1.).

Comment: This may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_trajectory

Comment: @CharlesTucker3 I didn't get you very clearly, the mass has no initial velocity.

Comment: @Shadow Ah, missed that info, thanks...

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, but can you please summarise, I'm having a hard time understanding anything in there

Comment: "For all ellipses with a given semi-major axis the orbital period is the same, regardless of eccentricity." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period

Comment: Do you need an analytic answer, or is it sufficient to do numerical integration?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Please can you provide an analytic answer.

Comment: Sorry, I agree that Wikipedia page is a bit confusing. And your problem doesn't need the general solution because you're treating the Sun as a point, so you can just use Kepler's square-cube rule, as mentioned by gandalf61.

Comment: @shadow I'm long out of school, which means I don't have to do integrals any more :-) .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft lol, no problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is usually tackled using Kepler's Third Law. The trajectory of this object falling into the sun is actually 'half' of a degenerate ellipse with semi-major axis equal to R/2. 
From Kepler's Third Law: $ \frac{a^3}{T^2}=\frac{GM}{4 \pi^2} $
$$ T=\sqrt{\frac{4 \pi^2 a^3}{GM}} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi^2 R^3}{2GM}} $$
So the result is:
$$ \Delta t = \frac{T}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{\frac{R^3}{2GM}}$$
As far as I'm aware, it is very difficult to find the time it takes a body to travel between two arbitrary positions on an elliptical orbit (you'd basically have to compute the area swept by the body), so calculating that integral is probably hopeless.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome, never thought about that approach, thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it's quite a neat hack I found out about from an IPhO problem (Question 3 - IPhO 2012).

Comment: Note that if you use units of au & years, then $\mu=GM=4\pi^2$.

Comment: The integral for the full 2D elliptical case isn't soluble in terms of elementary functions. However, the radial trajectory *is* soluble. See Time as a function of distance, Elliptic trajectory in the Wikipedia article on the radial trajectory that I linked previously.

Comment: “Calculating that integral is probably hopeless” ... except that we *already know* the orbital period of a body in an elliptical orbit with the same semi-major axis as the Earth’s orbit ...

Comment: Probably I didn't phrase my answer clearly enough. I was referring to the general case when we aren't interested in the orbital period, but in the parametrization of the orbit in terms of time. Calculating, for example, how much time it takes for the object to fall from R to R/6 isn't trivial.

Comment: Well, now I wonder how this answer compares with the one I stole from Wikipedia, which just looks at Gm/r^2  for two static bodies, i.e. no transverse speed at start.

Comment: Well, I guess this answer is a special case which happens to have a nicer solution.

Comment: @gandalf But this (degenerate) ellipse has a major axis of 1 au, i.e., its semi-major axis is 0.5 au. And so the falling time is $\frac1{4\sqrt 2}$ year.

Comment: @PM2Ring The full degenerate ellipse (i.e. the straight line radial “orbit”) extends an equal distance the other side of the sun, so its semi-major axis is 1 au.

Comment: @gandalf61 No, the Sun *must* be a focus of the ellipse. And the focus of an extremely eccentric ellipse is very close to the periapsis, not near the centre of the ellipse. If you were correct, the falling time would be 0.25 years, but the solution given by S. Stefan's and Carl's methods is ~0.17677 years.

Comment: @PM2Ring Got it - yes, you are right., semi-major axis is 0.5 au It is the limiting case of a very tight sun-grazing orbit which whips around the far side of the sun and back again.

Comment: @gandalf61 Thanks, I had the same misconception.

Answer (score 1):

Surprise :-) , [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_for_a_falling_body) to the rescue.

> The time $t$ taken for an object to fall from a height $r$ to a height $x$, measured from the centers of the two bodies, is given by:
> $$t={\frac {\arccos {\Big (}{\sqrt {\frac {x}{r}}}{\Big )}+{\sqrt {{\frac {x}{r}}\ (1-{\frac {x}{r}})}}}{\sqrt {2\mu }}}\;r^{3/2}$$
> where $\mu =G(m_{1}+m_{2})$ is the sum of the [standard gravitational parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) of the two bodies.

Glad they did it; I would hate to have worked out that antiderivative myself.

Comment: Wait, is that what you get if you integrate that mess (i.e. (3) of my approach), in a more general form?

Comment: @shadow, yes. Take a look at the linked page

Comment: @PM2Ring That would take work, and I'm deathly allergic!  The wikipedia page source might have the mathjax code

Comment: @Shadow That integral is... unpleasant, although Wolfram Alpha, etc, can do it. And it's easy enough to verify by taking the derivative.

Comment: @Shadow Actually, the integral isn't too bad, once you realise that a trig substitution is involved. Let $x=r\cos^2\theta$, and then it's pretty straightforward, assuming you know how to integrate $\cos^2\theta$.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/53896/12102) links to a video with the antiderivative worked out step by step; it looks like you made a wise call!